# "Login failed" running dtutil from a client but works when run locally on the server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm unable to execute DTUTIL remotely (from my laptop), however when I run from on the SQL server instance it is successful. The command is below, which is run from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn

```
DTUTIL /FILE C:\temp\<PackageFile>.dtsx /copy SQL;<Packagename> 
          /DestServer <servername> /DestU <Username> /DestP <Password>
```

Will return a error:

```
       Error (0xC0014014) while checking for the existence of package "Pac
       kage" on SQL Server.
       Could not save package "Package" because of error 0x80040E4D.
       Description: Login failed for user Domain\user'.
       Source: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please advise.

Comment: The error says this is an authentication issue. Do you usually use Windows or SQL authentication to connect to the server? Are you running the tool using the same Windows account on your laptop and on the server? Can you connect from your laptop using other tools like sqlcmd.exe?

Comment: I use both windows for integration services and SQL for DB. No, unable to run cmd under that account ( run as different user) and failed. Will logon to laptop using account and check if I cannot via that way.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that this issue is result of double hop? I found an article where the author uses powershell to aide in the deployment. I believe that this is a credential delegation issue.

> Click here [deploying packages using dtutill with powershell part 1](http://maxt2posh.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/deploying-ssis-packages-using-dtutil-exe-with-powershell-part-1%E2%80%A6)

Your only option might be using something like powershell and using CredSSP to pass your credentials.

> Powershell CredSSP
>
> > http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx

I lean this way because if you read these comments I found about remote deployment
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/dcd13796-9b9e-4cfe-92a7-adcaa8b6d196/), MSDN Student says

*"I wish there was an easy way for remote deployment of packages .... dtutil brings in the complexity of remote processes and kerberos delegation."*

Hopefully this helps lead you to some better answers. I can't really help anymore without knowing specifics about your network setup.